# Using numpy random and pandas sample to make a random choice from a DF, not random distribution of choices after 100k runs

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

I have made a small script for my D&D group that, when a spell is cast, chooses whether or not another random spell gets cast, the ordinal spell gets cast, or nothing happens (with a 50%, 25%, 25% ratio, respectively).

In order to do this, I made a `pd.DataFrame` of every possible spell in the game (using data from http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/spells), and then appended two data frames (one that says "Original Cast" in the spell name and the other that says "Nothing Happens"), each with `len  == len(df)/2` so as to have a full `df` twice the size of the original, as shown in the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from os import urandom

def create_df():

    df = pd.read_csv("all_spells.csv", encoding="utf-8")
    df = df.dropna(axis=0, subset="Spell Name")
    df_b = df[~df["Spell Name"].str.contains(r"\((.*?)\)")].reset_index(drop=True)


    OG_cast = ['Orginal Cast' for i in range(int(len(df.index)/2))]
    No_Magic = ['Nothing Happens' for i in range(int(len(df.index)/2))]
    Nadda = [None for i in range(int(len(df.index)/2))]

    df_same = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns,
                           data={
                               df.columns[0]: OG_cast,
                               df.columns[1]: Nadda,
                               df.columns[2]: Nadda,
                               df.columns[3]: Nadda,
                               df.columns[4]: Nadda
                           })
    df_nothing = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns,
                           data={
                               df.columns[0]: No_Magic,
                               df.columns[1]: Nadda,
                               df.columns[2]: Nadda,
                               df.columns[3]: Nadda,
                               df.columns[4]: Nadda
                           })

    df_full = pd.concat([df_b, df_same, df_nothing], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)

    return df_full
```

`df_full.sample(n=10)` is shown below, for reference.

```
+-----+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------------+
|     | Spell Name                 | School        | Casting Time   | Range   | Duration                       | Components   |
+=====+============================+===============+================+=========+================================+==============+
|  12 | Psychic Scream             | Enchantment   | 1 Action       | 90 feet | Instantaneous                  | S            |
+-----+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------------+
|  18 | True Polymorph             | Transmutation | 1 Action       | 30 feet | Concentration up to 1 hour     | V S M        |
+-----+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------------+
| 670 | Orginal Cast               |               |                |         |                                | nan          |
+-----+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------------+
| 193 | Conjure Woodland Beings    | Conjuration   | 1 Action       | 60 feet | Concentration up to 1 hour     | V S M        |
+-----+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------------+
| 795 | Orginal Cast               |               |                |         |                                | nan          |
+-----+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------------+
| 218 | Otilukes Resilient Sphere | Evocation     | 1 Action       | 30 feet | Concentration up to 1 minute   | V S M        |
+-----+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------------+
| 353 | Levitate                   | Transmutation | 1 Action       | 60 feet | Concentration up to 10 minutes | V S M        |
+-----+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------------+
| 839 | Nothing Happens            |               |                |         |                                | nan          |
+-----+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------------+
| 459 | Silent Image               | Illusion      | 1 Action       | 60 feet | Concentration up to 10 minutes | V S M        |
+-----+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------------+
| 719 | Orginal Cast               |               |                |         |                                | nan          |
+-----+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------------+
```

I then call the script below to get what happens when a spell is cast.

```
    df = create_df()

    seed = int(np.random.uniform(0, len(df.index)*10))
    spell = df.sample(1, random_state=seed)['Spell Name'].values[0]
    print("The spell cast is:", spell)
```

To test if this was giving me the distribution I wanted (50% of the time, there is a random spell cast, 25% nothing happens, and 25% the spell works as intended), I ran

```
    OC = 0
    NH = 0
    N = 0
    for i in range(100000):
        seed = int(np.random.uniform(0, len(df.index)*10))
        arb = df.sample(1, random_state=seed)['Spell Name'].values[0]
        # print(arb)
        if arb == 'Orginal Cast':
            OC += 1
        elif arb == 'Nothing Happens':
            NH += 1
        else: N += 1


    print(OC, NH, N)
```

And instead of getting 50/25/25 (for the things stated above), I get an extremely consistent 47/26.5/26.5. Does anyone know why this is happening? And does anyone have a better idea and random sampling so as to more consistently get the correct ratio?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the original dataframe (in a reproducible format)

Comment: I think you should ask questions instead of trying to delegate your work. To ask questions instead of delegating your work, you need to be able to isolate the problem and express it as a [mre].

Comment: @PandaKim The work is done. I am asking if anyone knows why I am not getting the correct ratio from random sampling.

Comment: When you are creating your `OG_cast` and `No_Magic` dataframes you are using the `df` frame instead of `df_b` which seems to be larger.

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent"? 47/26.5/26.5 was the result after 100000 iterations? did you plot  this distribution versus iterations and find it converging?

Comment: What size is the original df from "all_spells.csv"? I didn't see that information. Is it an odd or even number? `int(len(df.index)/2)` isn't necessarily 50% *exactly*...

Comment: Please add size of each dataframe involved as control

Comment: @OCa the original df was 575. But that shouldn't effect the ratio by much

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch so `df` has size 575. What size do `df_b` and `df_full` have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems unnecessarily complicated.

In the end you want that "*when a spell is cast, randomly chooses whether or not that spell gets cast, another random spell gets cast, or nothing happens.*".

So just do that, no need to create complex pandas structures:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# load dataset
df = pd.read_html('http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/spells')[0]

def cast_spell(df, spell, p=[0.25, 0.5, 0.25]):
    # check the input is valid
    assert spell in df['Spell Name'].values
    
    # randomly pick one of the outcomes
    match np.random.choice(['Original Spell', 'Other Spell', 'Nothing happens'], p=p):
        case 'Original Spell':
            return f'The "{spell}" spell was successfully cast.'
        case 'Nothing happens':
            return f'The "{spell}" spell failed: nothing happens.'
        case _:
            other = df.loc[df['Spell Name'].ne(spell), 'Spell Name'].sample(1).item()
            return f'The "{spell}" spell failed. "{other}" was cast instead.'

cast_spell(df, 'True Strike')
```

Example of calling 20 times `cast_spell(df, 'True Strike')`:

```
The "True Strike" spell failed. "Poison Spray" was cast instead.
The "True Strike" spell was successfully cast.
The "True Strike" spell failed. "Lightning Lure" was cast instead.
The "True Strike" spell failed. "Thaumaturgy" was cast instead.
The "True Strike" spell was successfully cast.
The "True Strike" spell was successfully cast.
The "True Strike" spell failed. "Light" was cast instead.
The "True Strike" spell failed. "Infestation" was cast instead.
The "True Strike" spell was successfully cast.
The "True Strike" spell failed. "Mind Sliver" was cast instead.
The "True Strike" spell failed: nothing happens.
The "True Strike" spell failed. "Lightning Lure" was cast instead.
The "True Strike" spell failed: nothing happens.
The "True Strike" spell failed: nothing happens.
The "True Strike" spell failed. "Mage Hand" was cast instead.
The "True Strike" spell was successfully cast.
The "True Strike" spell failed: nothing happens.
The "True Strike" spell was successfully cast.
The "True Strike" spell failed. "Primal Savagery" was cast instead.
The "True Strike" spell failed. "Frostbite" was cast instead.
```

##### pure python variant

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.read_html('http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/spells')[0]

spells = set(df['Spell Name'])

def cast_spell(spells, spell, p=[0.25, 0.5, 0.25]):
    assert spell in spells

    choice = random.choices(['Original Spell', 'Other Spell', 'Nothing happens'],
                            weights=p)[0]
    if choice == 'Original Spell':
        return f'The "{spell}" spell was successfully cast.'
    elif choice == 'Nothing happens':
        return f'The "{spell}" spell failed: nothing happens.'
    else:
        other = random.choice(list(spells-{spell}))
        return f'The "{spell}" spell failed. "{other}" was cast instead.'

cast_spell(spells, 'True Strike')
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want to randomly choose, I want to randomly choose based on there being a 50% something random is cast, a 25% change the original spell is cast, and a 25% nothing happens. That's why I made the weird dataframe. But for some reason I can't get that ratio even with a random sampling.

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch that's unclear, can you please provide examples of the expected output?

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch I think the provided answer is doing exactly what you asked for. Take a look at the [choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) method and the parameter p.

Comment: Also note that I used the DataFrame and its `sample` method to show you how to do that with a bit of pandas, but if you really just want to pick a random spell, then you could convert the spell name column to a set and only pick a random item from that. I added a pure python variant.

Comment: @mozway would you recommend the pure python variant?

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch if you just want the spell name and not the other columns, probably.